# как переопределить кнопку back, что бы она отрабатывала как UpHome

Tags: android

Кaк можно переопределить значение кнопки back, что бы по нажатию вызывалась не прядущая активность из стека, а отрабатывала как UpHome.

Comment: т.е. выйти на главную страницу приложения?

Comment: Нет, на ту активити, которая указана в манифесте в  android:parentActivityName. 
Хотя если есть вариант как вернутся на главную страницу, параллельно прибив все остальные активности в стеке, то тоже подойдет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(активити_откуда.this, активити_куда.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish(); // закрываем эту активити
}
```